# Laravel Elequent Count from Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to get the count of 2 columns('published', 'expires') in Laravel 5.6.

I want my results count to only show if the item is published, not expired or there is no expiration date.

my code:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'); 

 $numrecords = deals::where('published',1)
    ->orwhereDate('expires', '=', '')
    ->orwhereDate('expires', '>=', $today)
    ->count();
```

thanks

Nabi

Comment: Please, make a clearer question. At this moment, your question doens't make sense. Give us your desired behavior ("I want my deals that are published AND has an expiration date after today OR ... ")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$numrecords = deals::where('published', 1)
    ->where(function($q){
        return $q->whereNull('expires')
            ->orwhereDate('expires', '>=', Carbon::today());
    })
    ->count();
```

Above should give you :

```
SELECT * FROM deals
WHERE
published = 1 AND 
( expires IS NULL OR DATE(expires) >= today_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the queries you are supposed to write: (today is a Laravel function)

```php
// 1. if the item is published
$item->where('published', true);

// 2. expire date is after today
$item->where('expiry_date', '>', today());

// 3. expire date is null
$item->whereNull('expiry_date');

//4. emit expired items
$item->where('expiry_date', '>', today());
```

I think some of your check conditions are wrong.

Also, your logic is very messy as well. I am not sure what condition you are trying to write, but do write it down,  under what condition, is an item considered into the count, then you decide to use `where` or `orWhere`.